# Unable to fetch data from json through codable swift

Tags: json, swift, codable

This is json code:

```
{
  "status":"success",
   "data":
     [
       {"id":"3",
        "city_name":"Delhi",
         "city_image":"delhi.png"},
       {"id":"4",
        "city_name":"Mumbai",
        "city_image":"tickmark.png"}
     ]
 }
```

My Swift Code :

```
struct city: Decodable{
    let status : String
    let id: String
    let data : String
    let city_name: String
    let city_image: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let jsonUrl = "http://parking.onlinekiduniya.org/api/cityList.php"
        let url = URL(string: jsonUrl)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([city].self, from: data!)
                for city in cities {
                print(city.id)
            }
            }
            catch {
                print("we got error")
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
let cities = try JSONDecoder().decode([city].self, from: data!)
```

with

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
let cities = root.data
cities.forEach {
   print($0.id)
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let status: String
    let data: [City]
}

struct City: Codable {
    let id, cityName, cityImage: String // you can use snake case also

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case cityName = "city_name"
        case cityImage = "city_image"
    }
}
```

Your root is a dictionary not an array

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick response. I replaces this line of code but now I am getting error .  -----Variable used within its own initial value

Comment: @VidurBahl follow the whole answer content

Comment: Ok what should be print line for printing my data .? Thanks @sh_khan

Comment: Thanks a lot bro you saved my day :) Very much appreciate your fast and accurate response. Also which is the good way to learn json Integration in swift. ? Thanks once again

Comment: @VidurBahl first you should learn how to structure the json correctly with https://jsonlint.com/ then generate swift files with https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Also if you can help me inserting these data into table view ?? would that be possible ? thanks